# Passing variables to another page with url - PHP

Tags: php, session, variables

I want to execute some PHP code by clicking on a link and Passing variables to another page with url
Pleas help me.

Such WordPress Site: https://www.armandl.com/?p=5123

Comment: You overwrite `$_SESSION['status']` on your first page so it's always going to be `1`

Comment: `echo '<a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">X</a>';` - do you know what that syntax is and what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `$_SESSION['status']` to `0` and then set it to `1`, so it will always be `1`.  Additionally, the link you click has nothing to do with the session vars.

**Page 1:**

Normally to get just one variable from one page to another via hyperlink you would add it to the URL as a query parameter and access it using `$_GET`:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="page2.php?status=0">No</a>';

    echo '<a href="page2.php?status=1">Yes</a>';
?>
```

**Page 2:**

You also need to check if `$_GET['status']` is set:

```
<?php
    if    (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 0) {
        echo "No !";
    }
   elseif (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 1) {
        echo "Yes !";
   }
   else {
        echo "NOT set !";
   }
?>
```

Now, if you want it to be accessible on other pages without passing in the URL, then set it as a session var:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['status'] = $_GET['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any type of variable  & string instead of the 0,1 selection.

Example:

```
if (isset($GET["newpwd"])){
 if ($_GET["newpwd"] == "passwordupdated"){
   //code goes here
 }
}
```

To pass from another page you would use something like:

```
header("Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=passwordupdated");
```